# bootstrap-select: how to find selected option and remove or add class

Tags: jquery

[jsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n1zz8kkw/18/) shows 3 links. If you click the "Show Select options" link, you will see 3 options with middle one already selected. How can I remove or add the `.active` class from/to selected option (which would remove or add the background-color)?

I can see this path (with the developer tool):

```
html > body > div#searchSelect > div.btn-group.bootstrap-select.open > div.dropdown-menu.open > ul.dropdown-menu.inner > li.selected.active > a
```

and I try to use all different ways like: `$("#searchSelect").find(".selected").removeClass('active');` 
`$("#searchSelect").find(".selected").addClass('active');`

but I can't find a way to do this. This is kind of weird example, but I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What you need to achieve? can you explain more.?

Comment: Simply I need to add a class `.active` to the selected option because it's missing when I dynamically populate my select from ajax request after setting the default value. It shows fine but only for the second click of the link for showing my select's dropdown. I tried to refresh or render again but nothing helps, so I want to add this active class manually and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can update like that:

```
  $("#link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    $("#searchSelect").show();

    //$("#idSelect").selectpicker("val", "Janet");

   setTimeout(function () {
        $('#idSelect').selectpicker('toggle');
        });

   $("#searchSelect").find(".selected").removeClass('active');


  });
```

jsFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Devasnsh_Kumar/n1zz8kkw/44/

Comment: Thank you for helping, I had to do it in a different way but for this examples works fine. You made me sure that the code `$("#searchSelect").find(".selected").addClass('active');` is correct, so I had to find the right place to make it work.